# mysql count distinct days in a month

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

in mysql `table1` i have column `dateofreport` and there are few records per day e.g.

```
dateofreport 
2013-05-31
2013-05-31
2013-05-30
2013-05-30
2013-05-30
2013-05-29
2013-04-31
2013-04-31
2013-04-31
2013-04-02
```

I want to find out how many distinct days there are for a month,
so result should be: 2013-May : 3, 2013-April : 2

i can  do distinct days in all table: `SELECT  COUNT( DISTINCT dateofreport ) FROM table1`  or distinct months but i don't know how to group it by months.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
DATE_FORMAT(`dateofreport`,'%Y-%M') as months 
FROM table1
```

Comment: There is no April 31.

Comment: @DevlshOne, not according to MySQL!  :-)  We can set strict mode to make that into an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM dateofreport) AS ym,
    COUNT(DISTINCT dateofreport) AS count
FROM table1
GROUP BY ym
```

The only reason I use EXTRACT() is that it's ANSI standard SQL, IIRC.  Both types of function are likely to cause temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateofreport, '%Y-%M') AS months,
    COUNT(DISTINCT dateofreport) AS count
FROM table1
GROUP BY months
```

Comment: Try it again, I had an extra ")"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM dateofreport) AS distinctmy,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DAYOFYEAR(dateofreport)) AS uniquedays 
FROM
    table1 
GROUP BY distinctmy
```

*OUTPUT*

[image]